# PHP Laravel read files from another drive

Tags: php, laravel, directory

I'm currently in the learning curve of Laravel.
I was wondering if there is a way using the `Storage::` in Laravel to access files from another harddrive (using Windows).

Example, I've got Xampp with Laravel setup on drive C:, but I want to access files on E: outside of website directory. I've tried using `Storage::files('E:')` and `File::files('E:')` but that clearly doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not tested this myself, but from the documentation page, i take it you need to edit the `filesystem.php` config file to something like:

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app'),
    ],
    'partitionE' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => 'E:/', // not really sure about this
    ]
    // the rest of it
];
```

And then accessing files like

```
Storage::disk('partitionE')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

If all this fails, you *could* go with a `symlink` and create a link to your `E:` inside your project folder.

Comment: This works just perfect. Just tested it.
Did not think i would have to add the drive to the config. But that works.
Thank you!